# angular js ui-grid double click on row not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I want to call a function myFunc on doubleclick of ui-grid row.
for that I have used

```
<ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.myFunc()">
```

but it is not being called and showing no error.

here is the calling part of html :

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection class="gridStyle" 
    ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.myFunc()">
</div>
```

and here is the js script:

```
    var myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                        {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

          var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection']);
          app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
                 $scope.data = myData;
                 $scope.mySelections = [];

                 $scope.gridOptions = {
                     data :'data',
                     selectedItems : $scope.mySelections,
                     enableRowSelection: true,
                     //enableSelectAll: true,
                     selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
                     rowHeight: 35,
                     showGridFooter:true,
                     enableRowHeaderSelection :false,
                     multiSelect:false,
                     enableSelectAll:false,
                     enableFullRowSelection:true,
                   //  noUnselect: true
                 }


$scope.myFunc = function ()
                         {
                       alert('you double clicled!');
                          };



                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .

      });
```

Comment: Did my answer below help?  Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Its typo in directive name.

It should be

```
ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.myFunc()"
```

instead of

```
ngdblclick="grid.appScope.myFunc()"
```

Comment: Which ui-grid version you're using?

Comment: I m using Ui-grid 3.0.3

Comment: @TilakPatil where you wanted to make `ng-dblclick` to be working?? currently you binded to grid directly..

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var dblClickRowTemplate =
    //same as normal template, but with ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.myFunc()"
    "<div ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid\" ng-dblclick=\"grid.appScope.myFunc()\" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid=\"rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }\" role=\"{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}\" ui-grid-cell></div>";
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    rowTemplate: dblClickRowTemplate,
    //selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    //enableSelectAll: true,
    selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
    rowHeight: 35,
    showGridFooter: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableSelectAll: false,
    enableFullRowSelection: true,
    data: [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
           {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
           {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
           {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
           {name: "Enos", age: 34}]
  }
  $scope.myFunc = function() {
    alert('you double clicled!');
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.css" />
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection class="gridStyle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.